# Geometry - Squares

Tags: geometry

How can I show, that a straight line $p$ has to go through the midpoint $M$ of a square $ABCD$ in order to cut it in half?

My idea:
If I surround the square with a circle, the midpoints are the same. Now the diameter of the circle is cutting the square in two halfs and goes through the midpoint. Might this be a visual proof or is there a more elegant mathematical solution.

Comment: Show that a line $p$ that goes through the midpoint divides the area in half.  Then consider a function from every line parallel to $p$ that gives the ratio the square is divided by.  Can you show that no line other than $p$ would have a ratio of 1:1?

Comment: It doesn't just have to be the diagonal -- any straight line that goes through the midpoint cuts the squares into congruent shapes.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Ok, i'll try it. Your idea seems interesting.

Comment: What does "cut it in half" mean?  ANd what does "the midpoint of a square" mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p$ has to intersect the square (with side long $l$) in two points, suppose they belong to sides $AB$ and $CD$, call them respectively $P $ and $Q$, then $AP=x$ and $DQ=y$. The Area of the trapezoid $APQD=\frac {l(x+y)}2$. Imposing it to be $\frac {l^2}2$ we get $x+y=l$ so $PB=y$ and $CQ=x$. Then $APQD$ and $PBCQ$ are congruent trapezoids. Do you see solution now?

Comment: "suppose they belong to sides AB and CD"  I think you should explain why the line can't pass through adjacent sides.

Comment: @fleablood just because otherwise the created triangle is contained in an half-square triangle, so the area must be fewer

Answer (score 0):

The parallel to $p$ through $M$ cuts the square into two congruent (by point reflection at $M$) parts. Hence the area of the square between these two parallel lines must be zero.

[image]

Comment: So you say that if p supposedly cuts the square into two halfs and the parallel does the same, the area has to be 0. It clearly isn't on the picture.

Comment: @calculatormathematical Exactly. The only way to make the area 0 is if the parallel through $M$ equals $p$, i.e.,  by starting with $p$ passing through $M$. The mileage might vary with a different - not connected - shape instead of the square.